# biblatex: Problem with \printbibliography / BiBLaTeX when \AtBeginSection Contains a Frame

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, biblatex

I have a basic MWE [after removing 400 unrelated code lines :(] containing a `beamer` presentation with a bibliography that is generated by `biblatex`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz}

\usepackage{biblatex}   

\begin{filecontents}{BibDatabase.bib}
@book{Miller2012,
    author = {Adam Miller},
    title = {Clever Book Title},
    date = {2012},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{BibDatabase.bib}    

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\begin{document}

\section{test}
\begin{frame}
  \cite{Miller2012}
  \printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

## Depending on the content of `\AtBeginSection` I get different errors

### Error 1 (`plain` option active)

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\begin{tikzpicture}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}
```

> ```
> ! Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.
> \endframe ->\egroup 
>                     \begingroup \def \@currenvir {frame}
> l.30 \end{frame}
>
> I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
> spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
> you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
> the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
> deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
> ```

### Error 2 (`plain` option *not* active / `tikzpicture` removed)

```
\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}%[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection{
    \begin{frame}%[plain]
    %\begin{tikzpicture}
    %\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{frame}
}
```

> ```
> ! Missing \endcsname inserted.
> <to be read again> 
>                    \vrule 
> l.30 \end{frame}
>
> The control sequence marked <to be read again> should
> not appear between \csname and \endcsname.
> ```

### No Error (no content at all)

```
\AtBeginSection{
%   \begin{frame}%[plain]
%   \begin{tikzpicture}
%   \end{tikzpicture}
%   \end{frame}
}
```

[image]

> Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Are you sure the `tikzpicture` is relevant? I'd expect this to fail without that.

Comment: @cfr You are right. It also fails without a `tikzpicture`. I wotked on a theme for about 20 hours, including the AtBeginSection stuff, now I wanted to add a bibliography and  the error occurs. I updated the question accordingly.

Comment: @cfr Ahhhh. Can it be that it has to to with the automatic heading that biblatex is including? `\printbibliography[heading=none]` seems to help. But why couldn't I google the problem - others must have had the same problem (combination of biblatex and AtBeginSection).

Comment: I don't think it is `biblatex`'s fault here, as far as I can see the problem arises as soon as you have a `\section` command within a frame. Here that is 'hidden' in `\printbibliography`.

Comment: @moewe Thanks. I would have thought that my combination here is not too exotic.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner But what would the correct behaviour be, in your view? That `\printbibliography` never creates a heading? Or that `\AtBeginSection` doesn't permit the inclusion of a `frame`?

Comment: Note that, by default, `\printbibliography` in a `frame` is no problem. I've used it on occasion and it is always fine. But I rarely use `\AtBeginSection`. @moewe Yes.

Comment: @cfr Ok - I get your point. Maybe I am just frustrated because I was stripping down my code for some time in order to narrow down the problem ;). Thanks for the help - as always.

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner I can certainly sympathise with the frustration ;).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\printbibliography` calls `\section*`. Hence, you are trying to nest a `frame` within a `frame`, which cannot work.

Either use

```
\AtBeginSection[]{%
  ...
}
```

to avoid the customisation stuff in unnumbered sections, or use

```
\printbibliography[heading=none]
```

to avoid `\printbibliography` creating a section heading.

Comment: Great! Thanks!. I just had the same idea. It seems to be a **bug** or an **incompatibility** - would you agree?

Comment: @Dr.ManuelKuehner Not really. More misuse of the commands ;).